# Return Value After OnClick

Tags: javascript, jquery, promise, jquery-deferred

I am trying to retrieve a value from a button click and store it in a variable. The problem is that the user can arbitrarily click the button and I am trying to log the result of the button click at run time. I have been reading about promises and I am not sure how to implement them in my current code if they are necessary at all. I am not sure if I should even be worried about returning the result and instead pass the variable into the next function call.

startGame()

```
$("#play_btn").click(function() {
    if ($(".icons i").hasClass("selected")) {
      $("h5").remove();
      $(".icons").remove();
      $("button").remove();

      // I can pass the variable into this function, but then I will just be chaining
      // function calls. Is this the best route?
      // buildBoard calls -> playGame() calls -> endGame()
      buildBoard();

      return icon;
    }
  });
```

main

```
$("document").ready(function() {

  /*
  My thought process was to record the icon in the "elements" object
  and then call buildBoard() from the document.ready() function after the 
  user had clicked the button
  */

  let elements = {};
  var deferred = $.Deferred();

  deferred
    .then(function() {
      return startGame();
    })
    .done(function(icon) {
      console.log(icon);
    });

  deferred.resolve();
});
```

Comment: If you just want to log the value when the button is clicked... $("#play_btn").click(function() {console.log(icon)}

Comment: I know I can do that. I wanted it to be stored in the main function call. In order to do that, it needs to be returned.

Comment: If the button can just be clicked once its *possible* to do it with promises. If its necessary is hard to tell. Could you provide a working sample?

Comment: @Jonasw https://codepen.io/chasenbettinger/pen/BZKzNK?editors=1010

Comment: I think this is not a good usecase for promises. As the user decides once which side he playes, one may simply store it in a global variable like var player="x"; ...

Comment: @Jonasw I thought global variables were frowned upon

Comment: @chasen bettinger global in the meaning of *scope high enough to be accessed from everywhere* ... so maybe in your dom ready function?

Comment: JS being event driven, it will be difficult to o it that way.  I would give X and O an onClick that sets a variable, and have the button onClick pick that up and pass it into the game.

Comment: Set up a 'global' object of your own e.g. tickTackGame and set values on it for your global values.  That ensures you won't get naming conflicts when you use e.g. tickTackGame.icon and keeps all your globals in one place.

Answer (score 1):

Using promises would look like this:

```
var chooseSide=new Promise(function(resolve){
  $("#play_btn").click(function() {
     if ($(".icons i").hasClass("selected")) {
       $("h5").remove();
       $(".icons").remove();
       $("button").remove();
       var icon="x";//todo
       resolve(icon);
       }
     });
});
```

So you can do

```
chooseSide.then(function(side){
   alert("you chose:"+side);
   startGame(side);
});
```

However, i dont know if this is really useful.